# Equivalent of FindControl in application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have different datetime object in my code.

I want to do something like that :

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date2 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date3 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date4 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date5 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date6 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date7 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date8 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date9 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date10 = new DateTime();

        string date = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            date + i = "2010-10-28 11:00"; //It's wrong just for imagine my case
        }
    }
}
```

In my loop, I want to assign the object date1 at a specific value. 
Then date2, date3 etc... Until date10.

I know an equivalent method "FindControl" on web but it's not existing apparently for an application.

Have you an idea to resolve my problem ?
Thanks

Comment: I give this sample to simplify my problem in fact I am already in a loop, thats why I need to get my object with his index. I don't wan't to have two loops with an arraylist

Comment: What do you mean by `I am already in a loop`. may be you need to provide some more info on your problem?

Answer (score 3):

I would use an array:

```
var dates = new DateTime[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dates[i] = DateTime.Parse("2010-10-28 11:00");
}
```

And access it with index:

```
dates[i - 1]
```

if `i >= 1 && i <= 10`